# HTML5 Form Input Required - with Canvas

Tags: html, forms, html5-canvas

I am trying to require a name and email to a signature pad.

It seems it submits without validating the requirement.  It will force the email validation if entered wrong.  But ignores validation if left blank for both name and email.

So once the signature pad is signed. It accepts the form without validation.

I have also tried

Thoughts.  Is this a Javascript signature issue?

```
      <!DOCTYPE HTML>
      <html>
      <head></head>
      <body>

      <form>
      <br><br>Name:
      <br><input type="text" name="sname" id="sname" value="" size=20 class=verd15 required />
      <br><br>Email:</span>
      <br><input type="email" name="semail" id="semail" validate="email" value="" size=20 class=verd15 required />

      <br><br>

        <div id="canvas">
            Canvas is not supported.
        </div>

        <script>
            zkSignature.capture();
        </script>
        <img id="saveSignature" alt="Saved image png"/>
        <table border=0 cellpadding=3 width=300>
        <tr>
        <td>
        <button type="button" onclick="zkSignature.send()" class=verd13>&nbsp; &nbsp; Sign &nbsp; &nbsp;</button>
        </td>
        <td align=right valign=top>
        <button type="button" onclick="zkSignature.clear()" class=verd10> Clear </button>
        </td>
        </tr></table>

        </form>


      </body>
      </html>
```

Comment: I have a feeling you forgot the HTML5 doctype `<!DOCTYPE html>` ?

Comment: We need a [mcve] and you left out your JS

Comment: No there is a DocType yes

Comment: You should at the very least edit the code in your question into a valid program. As it stands, there's no reference to the JS library, nor have you made mention of its name or source.  "zksignature" entered into google give 13,100 results. None of those on the first page seem relevant. Given that much of your program is a black box - it seems reasonable that you should at least mention the supplier of that black-box, unless of course you're soliciting guesses?

Comment: I just accomplished by looking on the other side of the Javascript. If not filled out properly, I just return to the signature pad with warning.  Seems quicker for now.  I'll look further into the Canvas or Javascript as cause...